# database text with html formatting, how to pull it into my asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server-2005

I have content that I want to load dynamically, the problem is it has some html formatting in it. What control should i pull the text into, is there a way to pull the text into a div or a label, along with the formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an asp:Literal:

Code behind:

myLiteral.Text = HtmlDecode(GetTextFromDB())

Comment: Just make sure to be careful about the kind of html formatting allowed. Being able to inject javascript into a database entry can be a source of XSS.

Comment: thank you i ahve never worked with an asp literal, how would i get the data from my sqldatasource to the literal

Comment: I would'nt use an sqlDataSource.  You can access your db through ADO or Linq and then set the Text property of the literal.